# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments: python-crontab

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I tried to use python-crontab in my module library. 
What I did:
- I installed pip with my homebrew package manager with the command:

```
brew install pip
```

After that I was just able to use it with the command 'pip2' instead of 'pip'.
With pip I installed python-crontab with

```
pip2 python-crontab
```

From [documetation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) I read that this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments
```

is produced when to use the wrong version of python-crontab.

I get this error and after that I checked my packages with

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

There it is written the correct version of python-crontab

I dont know. Probably I dont understand the relationship between pip package manager and installed python versions.

greets
SchoRsch

Comment: Try pip install instead of pip2

Comment: Move to the python2.7/Scipts in cmd promt and run 'pip install crontab'  instead of pip2

Comment: run the commands: pip2 -V and pip -V. It will show you which pip is for which for which python version.

Answer (score 0):

'pip' means the default python version you set. You can type 'python' in the console to check the version. And the pip2 means the python2 which the previous version of python which the system have. It's the similar setting as python. For example, when you installed anaconda and set the default python path as the anaconda path. The 'python' and 'pip' version is as same as anaconda.